# Spring JPA Specification-arg-resolver

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I am using the **tkaczmarzyk** [**specification-arg-resolver library**](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver) for filtering data in spring boot jpa. The issue is that client is sending date param in **yyyy-MM** format but in db I have in **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** format. I want to fetch all the record of that month.
I am looking for a way to fetch records from db of a given month via tkaczmarzyk specification-arg-resolver library by considering that we have date in yyy-MM format as stated above.

Comment: Hi. Have you resolved this issue? I have the same problem. But I need to convert yyyy-MM-dd to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format.